# What are the ways to control banners on solaris 10 for scp?

Tags: ssh, solaris, scp, solaris-10

I work with a farm of solaris 10 servers with some inconsistent behaviors in terms of displaying banners/motd.

This time, I am trying to do scp from one server to another. Between some servers I get no banner, and some I do.

I have already tried:

- creating .hushlogin file
- scp -q
- scp -o LogLevel=Error
- PrintMotd no in  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- LogLevel QUIET in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

I am already not getting banners when using ssh, but the banner with scp still persists in some servers, and I'd like to find a way to turn it off.

I haven't got admin rights but can make requests for changes to specific configs.

scp session sample:

```
usera@server20$ scp a.sh server43:/tmp
###################################################################
# This system is for the use of authorized users only.            #
# Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in #
# excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   #
# activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      #
# personnel.                                                      #
#                                                                 #
# Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  #
# and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         #
# evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the #
# evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       #
###################################################################

WARNING: Access to this computer system is limited to authorised users only.
Unauthorised users may be subject to prosecution under the Crimes
Act or State legislation.

a.sh                 100% |***********************************************************************************************************|   602       00:00
usera@server20$
```

ssh session sample from a server in the farm:

```
usera@server20$  ssh server43
LI002: usera is allowed 2 concurrent logins
Last login: Tue Jun 16 2015 17:30:05 from pts/2
server43:usera>
```

ssh session sample from outside the farm:

```
login as: usera
###################################################################
# This system is for the use of authorized users only.            #
# Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in #
# excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   #
# activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      #
# personnel.                                                      #
#                                                                 #
# Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  #
# and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         #
# evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the #
# evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       #
###################################################################

WARNING: Access to this computer system is limited to authorised users only.
Unauthorised users may be subject to prosecution under the Crimes
Act or State legislation.

Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
LI002: usera is allowed 2 concurrent logins
Last login: Tue Jun 16 2015 18:40:41 from pts/1
server43:usera>
```

Comment: You get the banner with `scp`, but you do not get it with `ssh` on the same server with the same account?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Are all the servers at the same patch/revision level?  Especially with respect to SSH?

Comment: yes, i believe they are. Both report 5.10 Generic_150400-12 on uname -a

Comment: SUNWsshcu, SUNWsshdr, SUNWsshdu, SUNWsshr, SUNWsshu reports 11.10.0,REV=2005.01.21.15.53

Comment: I do not even think it's possible to have a different banner for `ssh` and `scp`. Can you post an example of `ssh` and `scp` login?

Comment: updated the post to reflect example

Answer (score 0):

You've indicated that this SSH server is also doing regular SSH shell sessions as well as your desired `sftp` approach.  Also, the following answer applies toward the oldest OpenSSH version possible: `v4.0.0p1` (except otherwise where noted).  This answer applies toward latest Solaris 10 and 11 for they use OpenSSH v6.6p1,REV=2014.03.20

My solution offers both regular SSH as well as `scp`/`sftp`.

## Settings

The trick is to use the `Match User sftp` in the SSH server config with a couple of settings:

- `Banner`
- `PrintMotd`

### `Banner`

`Banner` setting is the filename whose contents of the specified file are sent to the remote user before authentication is allowed.  If the argument is `none` then no banner is displayed.  By default, no banner is displayed.

Base on the OP, you probably had `Banner yes` somewhere in your file, and that is ok for we can restrict that behavior without modifying that config line (more on this later).

### `PrintMotd`

`PrintMotd` specifies whether `sshd(8)` should print `/etc/motd` when a user logs in interactively.  (On some systems it is also printed by the
shell, /etc/profile, or equivalent.)  The default is `yes`.

You probably did not have `PrintMotd <anything>` in your `sshd_config` config file so the default is to always display the Message Of The Day.

## Setting Block

To fix your issue, let us assume that the username for this SFTP/SCP activity is `sftp`.

The setting block to paste and use for making any and all `sftp` user NOT see any banner nor any message-of-the-day (MotD) are:

```
Match User sftp
    Banner none
    PrintMotd no
```

## Placement of Settings

Our above setting block may go into one of the following filename:

- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (older distros using OpenSSH v7.3 or before, and up to `macOS` [12 Monterey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_version_history) version)
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/900-custom-match-sftp.conf` (since OpenSSH v7.3 after year 2016)

RARE: While not very likely (unless the system admin is complex or its a corporate environment), these above `Match user sftp` setting block must be placed and read before any `Match all`, `Match canonical`, or `Match final` block.

NOTE: Multi-file SSH server config loads its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` in ASCII order.  In multi-file config approach, it is common to use 2 or 3-digit number as a starting filename to ensure its proper read ordering.  Our `Match user` setting block needs to be placed before any `Match all`, `Match canonical`, or `Match final`, so our number would be before their `970-*` or `97-*` assuming that `9[7-9]-*` and `9[7-9][0-9]-*` are taken by other `canonical`/`final`/`all` setting blocks.

## Reload/Restart SSH Server

Then reload/restart the SSH server.

The next `scp` or `sftp` login attempt will no longer show any banner or message of the day.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this option: -o LogLevel=quiet

Comment: Tried it. The banner still shows.